# Caching data and Passing data between routes in angular 2?

Tags: angular

When I start my angular app, on init, I hit and endpoint which returns me data for a particular route, so when I go to the home page, I query the database for the home page data and return that. Likewise, when I go to the contact route, I query the database for the contact data and return that.  This requires a call to the database every time I navigate to a route.  So my question is sort of two parts.

1. Is it is possible when the application is loaded for the first time, I can get the data for all the pages and then when the user is visiting home, I just filter this object client side and when they visit contact, I can filter the data for that client side instead of hitting the endpoint?  How can I achieve this?
2. Second, once I have the data for the home and contact, what is the best way to cache the data, so I don't have to hit the endpoint or do I just keep reusing the object that I got back on when the application initially loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way of passing data between components is to use a service. *Since services in Angular 2 are singletons* *, when your other components request it, it will receive the same instance with your data. This is how you would achieve what you are looking for

**Service**

```
export class DataService {
  public dataOne: Data;
  public dataTwo: Data;
}
```

**BaseComponent**

```
...
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // Make your calls and populate these variables with the corresponding data
  this.dataService.dataOne = {};
  this.dataService.dataTwo = {};
}
...
```

**ConsumerComponent**

```
...
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // get the data you added in the base component
 var dataOne = this.dataService.dataOne; 
}
...
```

*Angular 2 Services are singletons **per provider**, so if you add it to providers in the `app.module.ts` it will be a true singleton, otherwise, you will get a new instance per provider.

Comment: "Since services in Angular 2 are singletons" is quite vague and without more context plain wrong. You could say "Since services in Angular 2 are singletons per provider". Because if you provide a service on a component, you get as many instances as there are component instances. Not really what I'd expect from a singleton ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the service will be used?  Would the service be passing around a client side object?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer fixed, got me on that one :D

Comment: Ah thanks for the example, so once I populate dataOne, it will be accessible in the consumer component and won't make another db call.  If my data contains an array of objects for each route, what is the best way to filter that?

Comment: can you make dataOne dataTwo based on all your different routes, and on your initialization add each routes data to each individual variable ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Are you saying if I have 5 components that use the same service, they each get their own instance? Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by this " and on your initialization add each routes data to each individual variable ? –"  I get back an array of objects, so one object will have a property for the route (home, for example) and the data. So when I am on the home page, I want to filter the data for the home page

Comment: @xaisoft it depends where you declare the provider for the service. Look at my bottom note on what he was talking about. 

just do your filtering when you first initialize. For example, in your service you will have `homeData` variable, then when you first get the data you do service.homeData = data[0] and then you have all your data filtered. In the home component you can do service.homeData; and you get your home data.

Comment: If the component has `@Component({ selector: 'foo', providers: [MyService] })` then yes - one `MyService` instance per `foo` component. If you just have `constructor(private myService:MyService) {}` and `@NgModule({ providers: [MyService]})` - then no. Where you provide a service defines how many instances you get and what instance injected where.

Comment: @EduardoDennis - the object will not just contain data for home though.  The object returned will contain data that is for all routes and within that object there will be another object that has the array of objects.  I guess i can do object.object[0]? but wouldn't I have to guarantee order?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use ngrx/store for this.

This strategy uses redux pattern for storing persistent data (application state) in your application in an immutable single source of truth, making it accessible in every single component of your application.

Your main store will be modified only by actions dispatched by your components, so all business logic won't be component-dependant, being possible to reuse functions (actions in this case) between components without rewriting them every single time.

In each component you will be able to select a slice of this main store and subscribe to it's changes, as this function returns an observable, so your components will always be up to date with your main store (state).

Take a look at these tutorials, they explain this concept really well: 
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngrx-guide
https://medium.com/stratajet-tech/a-beginners-guide-to-ngrx-store-bc2184d6d7f0

It's a little tricky at the beggining but trust me, as soon as you understand it, you will forget Angular services, event emitters, @input and @output to create component interaction and data reusability, and you will see how amazing it is to move your business logic away from your components and be able to reuse it from anywhere.

It really makes things super simple to use this concept.

Comment: I will have to take a deeper look. Initially, as you said, it looks confusing to me, so I sort of give up.

Comment: Trust me, learning ngrx is going to save your life, study it intensively and learn how to define types, interfaces and build reducer functions. This is the best approach to keep your app state totally under control. I'd say that it's good to use this concept even in small projects =)